# Countable number of arcs between two intervals

Tags: general-topology

First consider the two intervals $I_0=\{0\}\times [0,1]$ and $I_1=\{1\}\times [0,1]$ in the plane.

Suppose that, for each $n\in\omega=\{0,1,2,...\}$, $A_n$ is an arc (a homeomorphic image of $[0,1]$) contained in $\mathbb [0,1]^2 \setminus (I_0\cup I_1)$ except for having one endpoint in $I_0$ and the other endpoint in $I_1$.

And suppose $A_i\cap A_j=\varnothing$ when $i\neq j$.

We may assume $A_0=[0,1]\times \{0\}$ and $A_1=[0,1]\times \{1\}$.

It seems intuitively true that there should be an arc $A\subseteq [0,1]^2$ between $I_0$ and $I_1$ that misses $\bigcup _{n\in\omega} A_n$.

Is this true?

> MY ATTEMPT:
>
> First consider the entire closed connected region $T_0=[0,1]^2$
>   between $A_0$ and $A_1$ (as defined above).
>
> If there is no other $A_n$ in $T_0$, then we're done (the arc $A$ is
>   easy to find).
>
> Otherwise, choose the least $n>1$ such that $A_n\subseteq T_0$.
>
> Get a tube $T_1$ (homeomorphic to $[0,1]^2$) between $A_1$ and $A_n$.
>   So $T_1\cap A_0=\varnothing$.
>
> Now get $T_2$ by going from $A_n$ to $A_m$, where $m>n$ is least index
>   of any arc $A_m\subseteq T_1$.
>
> We can continue this process to get a nested sequence of compact
>   connected tubes $T_n$, so that $T_n$ misses $A_{n-1}$ for each
>   $n<\omega$.
>
> Then $T:=\bigcap T_n$ is a compact connected set from $I_0$ to $I_1$
>   that misses all $A_n$'s.   But does it contain an arc from $I_0$ to $I_1$?

EDIT (June 23): There are now two answers below, which claim opposite things.  I'll try to figure out which argument is flawed, but would appreciate any help.  Please note that I proved (above) that there is a continuum between $I_0$ and $I_1$ which misses all arcs $A_n$.  So does this mean @Colin 's answer is flawed?

Regarding @Santana 's answer:

[image]

Think about a sequence of arcs doing this. So $$A_0=[0,1]\times \{0\}$$ and for $n>0$, $$A_n=\text{graph of the function } f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb R \text{ where }f_n (x)=\frac{1}{2}|2x-1|+\frac{1}{2^n}.$$

This is not homeomorphic to any collection of horizontal arcs. Moreover this shows you cannot start at an arbitrary remaining endpoint.  Every arc beginning at a point in $\{0\}\times (0,1/2)$ and ending in $I_1$ must intersect some $A_n$.

Comment: What is $\omega$? Should the graphs of the arcs $A_n$ be disjoint or something? What do you mean by interior of an arc? As in the largest open contained in the graph? Because this will be empty in the Euclidean topology.

Comment: What's the answer to the analogous problem about arcs between two **points**? Is that easy?

Comment: @Demophilus My guess is that by the "interior" of an arc he means the arc minus its endpoints.

Comment: How are you going to miss just the two diagonal arcs?

Comment: In your question, the arcs are allowed to touch at the ends, aren't they? It seems you made a point of requiring only the **interiors** to be disjoint.

Comment: Given countably many disjoint continuous functions $f_n:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,$ can you find a continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ which is disjoint from all of them?

Comment: If you just have a countable collection of pairwise disjoint arcs in the plane, can you find another arc which is disjoint from all of them? In other words, **can a maximal collection of pairwise disjoint arcs be countable?**

Comment: Re edit 2: You have a tube that misses the first $n$ arcs, but some later arc may *cross* that tube.

Comment: @ForeverMozart Well, as you specifically said the arcs are in $[0,1]\setminus(I_0\cup I_1)$, you may want to replace $A_i\cup A_j=\emptyset$ with  $\overline{A_i}\cup\overline{ A_j}=\emptyset$. Remains to specifiy if for the new arc $A$ you demand $A\cap A_i=\emptyset$ or $\overline{A}\cap\overline{A_i}=\emptyset$? This may make a great difference as picking a bad starting point may cause your choice of endpoint be squeezed between $(1,0)$ and all $(1,\frac1n)$ ..

Comment: What is an ARC?  Is it a continuous injective $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R^2 $?

Comment: The closed topologist's sine curve is a counterexample to the general implication "compact connected set ... does it contain an arc from $I_0$ to $I_1$?"

Comment: @ForeverMozart What about the arc $\alpha:[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ defined as $\alpha(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left|2x-1\right|+\frac{1}{3}$? This lies between $f_1$ and $f_2$ and satisfies all other requirements.

Comment: @SantanaAfton Yes it does, but your final reduction implies that we could start at ANY point of $I_0$ or $I_1$ that is not an endpoint of one of the $A_n$'s, and reach the other side.

Comment: @ForeverMozart Consider some $f_n$ and $f_{n+1}$ as per your definition and any $y\in(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$. Then define an arc $\alpha$ given by $\alpha(x) = \frac{1}{2}|2x-1| + (y - \frac{1}{2})$. This lies between $f_n$ and $f_{n+1}$ has an endpoint on any arbitrary point which is not an endpoint of any $f_n$, for any $n$.

Comment: @SantanaAfton Correct.  But the point of my example was every arc beginning in $\{0\}\times (0,1/2)$ and ending in $I_1$ must intersect some $A_n$.  Your argument implies you could begin anywhere.

Comment: @ForeverMozart Your collection of arcs does not meet the conditions that I stated for the rest of the proof to work. Note that in reduction 2, I break the problem into two cases, then prove that in either case such an arc exists. Your collection falls into the first case. I'll edit that section -- I realize that I wasn't being explicit about the casework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will argue that the answer is no: there may be no such $A$.

**Lemma: there is a countable set of disjoint arcs from $I_0$ to $I_1$ such that any arc from $I_0$ to $I_1$ disjoint from this set has only finitely many $1$'s and $2$'s in the base-4 representation of its startpoint in $I_0$**

I will index the arcs using rational numbers $q=a/4^b\in[0,1]$, where $A_q$ will go from $(0,q)$ to $(1,q).$ The arcs will be constructed using induction on $b$ (restricting the numerator $a$ to not be a multiple of $4$, except for $q=0=0/4^0$).

For the base case $b=0$, take a straight line for the arc from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$, and a straight line for the arc from $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$.

Now assume $A_{a/4^b}$ and $A_{(a+1)/4^b}$ are given; these bound an open disc and we are free to choose sufficiently wiggly $A_{(4a+1)/4^{b+1}}$, $A_{(4a+2)/4^{b+1}}$, and $A_{(4a+3)/4^{b+1}}$ in this region to guarantee that the $x$-coordinate of any arc trapped between
$A_{(4a+1)/4^{b+1}}$ and $A_{(4a+3)/4^{b+1}}$ switches between $1/4$ and $3/4$ at least $b$ times.

Consider a new arc $A$ with starting point $(0,r)$, disjoint from all the $A_q$ constructed above. By construction, for each $b$, if the $b$'th base-4 digit of $r$ is $1$ or $2$, then $A$ switches between $1/4$ and $3/4$ at least $b$ times.
So $r$ cannot have infinitely many $1$'s or $2$'s in its base-4 representation, QED.

**Full result**

Plonk a scaled copy of the above construction into $[0,1/3]\times [0,1]$, and another copy in $[2/3,1]\times[0,1]$, restricting the second copy to arcs with $q\leq 1/2$. Join the first copy's $A_q$ to the second copy's $A_{q/2}$ by a straight line from $(1/3,q)$ to $(2/3,q/2)$. This rules out all the remaining starting points because the only numbers $q$ such that $q$ and $q/2$ both have only finitely many $1$'s and $2$'s in the base-4 representations are of the form $a/4^b$.

Comment: I've done a rough check and this seems to be correct.  I assume the two up-voters agreed as well.  Anyone else care to validate?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why the position of the arc between the $x=1/4$ and $x=3/4$ lines gives information about where the arc started from.

Comment: @ForeverMozart: if it helps, I can assure you that I did my best to find a substantial flaw, but could not.

Answer (score 1):

*Notation*: for any arc $A_n$, we denote endpoints as $e_n:=A_n\cap I_0$ and $v_n:=A_n\cap I_1$.

We consider two separate cases.

**Case 1:** Suppose that there exist two arcs $A_n$ and $A_m$ such that there is no arc $A_k$ such that $e_n<e_k<e_m$. This implies that $A_n$ and $A_m$ bound an open disk in $[0,1]^2$, and hence there is some arc $A$ that connects $I_0$ and $I_1$ satisfying our conditions.

**Case 2:** Suppose that for every pair of curves $A_n$ and $A_m$ such that $e_n<e_m$ there must exist another arc $A_k$ such that $e_n<e_k<e_m$. We now consider three reductions of the problem to prove that, in this case, such an arc still exists.

#### Reduction 1:

We may assume that each $A_n$ is a straight line. If we apply a homotopy that takes each $A_n$ to the straight line between its endpoints, we note that since homotopy classes of arcs on $[0,1]^2$ are identified by endpoints the ordering of the endpoints is preserved. Moreover, this preservation also implies that these straight lines are disjoint. We can imagine the action of this homotopy being similar to taking $I_1$ and slowly moving it to the right, pulling each arc taught.

#### Reduction 2:

We may assume that the two sets $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ and $\{v_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ are each order isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$, and hence that $e_i,v_i\in\mathbb{Q}$.

First, we note that for any two arcs $A_i$ and $A_j$, if $e_i<e_j$ then $v_i<v_j$, otherwise $|A_i\cap A_j|\ne\emptyset$. Moreover, since we are assuming that for any $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $e_n<e_m$ there exists some $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $e_n<e_k<e_m$, this implies that the set $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ is a countable linear order that is order dense. [Since we are assuming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311058/countable-number-of-arcs-between-two-intervals?noredirect=1#comment4803403_2311058) that $e_i\in(0,1)\times\{0\}$, there is no first or last element. Hence, by [Cantor's Theorem](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.pdf), this set is order isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q},<)$. The same argument applies for the set $\{v_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$. Applying this isomorphism and composing with the homeomorphism $\mathbb{Q}\to [0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ yields the second claim.

(Note that if we do not assume that $A_0$ and $A_1$ form the top and bottom sides of $[0,1]^2$ respectively, then we can follow these arcs to their endpoints on $I_1$ then find a homeomorphism that takes $[v_0,v_1]$ to $[0,1]$. Hence, this is a safe assumption to make.)

#### Reduction 3:

We may assume that all arcs are horizontal lines. Using the prior reduction, we shift endpoints -- preserving order -- along both $I_0$ and $I_1$ to form each curve to a horiztonal line.

#### Final Proof:

Now, the question is this:

> Given the arcs $A_x:=\{x\}\times[0,1]$ for every $x\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$, is there some arc $A$ with endpoints on $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ and $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ such that $A\cap A_x=\emptyset$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Clearly, the answer is yes! Take any vertical line corresponding to an irrational number $y\in(0,1)$, and this arc will satisfy our conditions.

Comment: I'm not even fully confident about reduction 1

Comment: I'm not 100% confident on 1 or 3 either, though I do believe they're true. Since what we're ultimately asking is if there is some disk bounded by arcs that intersects $I_0$ and $I_1$, we can just homotope these arcs to straight lines without changing the existence of such a disk.

Comment: Idea for reduction 1: Pick $A_1$. Together with the upper parts of the "walls" and a "ceiling" arc, we obtain a simple closed Jordan curve. By Riemann-Caratheodory, we obtain a homeomorphism to the same situation with $A_1$ replaced by a straight line. We can do the same with the lower part. The two homeomorphisms can be glued together by "syncing" the ways they map $A_1$ itself. If desired, we may similarly achieve that the homeomorphism leaves $I_0$ and $I_1$ fixed. Now proceed iteratively with $A_2, A_3,\ldots$, at each step affecting only the rectangle the arc lives in. (cont)

Comment: (cont) I think this sequence of homeomorphisms of $[0,1]^2$ should converge to a homeomorphism of $[0,1]^2$ that turns all $A_i$ to straight lines without changing their endpoints. -- We might even do reduction 3 along the way? (By the way, I suppose you mean *horizontal* in reduction 3)

Comment: I think that's a great justification for reduction 1, thank you. Do you mind if I include it in my answer? And yes, I do mean horizontal -- this whole time I was imagining arcs going top-to-bottom instead of how OP described it as left-to-right.

Comment: @SantanaAfton please see my edit above

Comment: My example above can be modified to satisfy Case 2 as follows.  $A_0$ stays the same.  Then $\{A_n:n>1\}$ is the collection of graphs of functions $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}|2x-1|+q$ where $q$ is a rational in $(0,1/2]$. But as before,  the starting point cannot be arbitrary.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the issue here. I am not claiming that an arc exists for any endpoints _in your picture_, but in the picture _that I create_ after applying the order isomorphic onto $\mathbb{Q}$. To apply my reductions to this example, I would straight out your lines and map them onto $\mathbb{Q}$. Then, take any irrational point and take the straight line. Then, map everything back into $\{0\}\times(1/2,1]$, then bend it all again. [Here is a rough sketch of what I mean](http://imgur.com/a/Mmj70)